# Count instances of a value in R

Tags: r, plot

```
 Data:-

 Date        Value
2010 Q1        x
2011 Q4        x
2010 Q1        x
2010 Q3        x
2015 Q2        x
2016 Q1        x
2015 Q1        x
2013 Q4        x
2012 Q3        x
```

I need to calculate the number of points in a individual year and plot them finally. so I wrote a code which does the job but it involves hard coding the loop range.

```
Code:-

require(zoo)
year=count=""
for (i in 2009:2016){
    year=c(year,i+1)
    count=c(count,length(data[which(data$Date>i & data$Date<i+1),1]))
}
year=year[2:length(year)]
count=count[2:length(count)]
plot(year,count)

Output:-
year    "2010" "2011" 2012" "2013" "2015" "2016"
count   "3" "1" "1" "1" "2""1"
```

I am looking for help in basically two things. First is how can I generalize the code and second is can I substitute the concatenate method as I always need to remove the first element of every vector at the end of the code. Thanks.

Comment: `table(data$Date)` gives your output if you just take the year, I don't really understand your data structure. It looks like date is a string (year with quarter) in your example data, but you treat it as a numeric year-only in the loop

Comment: @rawr Date is of Class 'yearqtr' and hence I tried comparing it and it worked. To use the table method I need to first separate out the year and then use it. It works either way. Thanks.

Comment: so you are using the zoo package? please note any extra packages in your question

Comment: @rawr Thanks is there any better way you know that I can compare dates?

Comment: It depends on your needs. if you like the year/quarter format, then use that (and since `zoo` is a common, well-known, well-supported package). most date and time classes including yearqtr are simply storing the value as a number, so you can compare dates like you would any other numeric value. For example, today's date is stored as the number of days since 01 Jan 1970 `as.numeric(Sys.Date())`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it (with some example values):

```
date <- c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013)
value <- rep('x', times = 9)
dat <- data.frame(date, value)
dates = unique(dat$date)
count <- c()
for(i in 1:length(dates)){
    n <- length(which(dat$date == dates[i]))
    count[i] <- n
}
output <- data.frame(dates, count)
```

If the "Date" field in your data has values other than the year which you don't want, you could use gsub or some other way of separating out just the years beforehand.

Comment: `data.frame(table(date))`

Comment: That's great, I did not know of that function.